# How to write bash actions to a file?

Tags: bash

I know that there is a way to write bash shell outputs to a file. However, I want to know what commands have been executed by an application as some of these executions are not outputted as a shell output.

So, is there a way to write commands, including outputs, that were executed to a file?

Answer (score 2):

if you run a bash script by calling it with:

```
bash -x yourbashscript.sh
```

you will see both the commands and the output give by the commands run.

Answer (score 0):

If you execute your script with `-x` (e.g. `bash -x <script>`) you will see every output.  If you want to run it normally without seeing the output (but redirect it to a file too), you can do   `bash -x <script> 2>/dev/null`

Normally the `-x` bit prints to stderr (2) and not stdout (1).

You could `set -x` from within the script where you want to (and `set +x` when not) and redirect all STDERR to a file like above (`scriptname.bash 2>coolfile.txt`).

Much beyond that, you'll need to resort to perl or python.